# Why isn't Ansible able to parse my azure dynamic inventory config file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, azure-rm

I am trying to set up a dynamic inventory for Ansible to use with Azure, but I am getting some messages as Ansible is not able to parse my yaml file.

What I did so far:

> 1. Created Azure Service Principal and added credentials to /home/user/.azure/credentials (I know they recommend placing them in
>      /home/.azure/credentials and I tried that, but it seems that my
>      Ansible looks for them in the /home/user directory.
> 2. I placed both the python plugin (the original, unedited plugin) and its yaml config file in /etc/ansible/inventory_plugins. The config
>      file looks like this:

```
plugin: azure_rm

include_vm_resource_groups:

- vm_1197_rg

auth_source: auto
```

> 3. Testing the functionality with: ansible all -m ping -i ./myazure_rm.yml

The output:

> ansible 2.8.1   config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg   configured
>   module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules',
>   u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']   ansible python module
>   location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible   executable
>   location = /bin/ansible   python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr  9
>   2019, 14:30:50) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] Using
>   /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file Skipping due to inventory
>   source not existing or not being readable by the current user azure_rm
>   declined parsing /etc/ansible/inventory_plugins/myazure_rm.yml as it
>   did not pass it's verify_file() method  [WARNING]: Unable to parse
>   /etc/ansible/inventory_plugins/myazure_rm.yml as an inventory source
>
> [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is
>   available
>
> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available.
>   Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

Comment: is there anyone who has worked with more than 1 resource groups. When I am trying with first resource group it works fine and give me the o/p of ansible-inventory but when I add another resource group in the list include_vm_resource_groups: it gives the same warning.. How to troubleshoot? I am Newbie in azure tried all my efforts to search on azure portal and stackoverflow but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I was using the wrong extension when running the command. I was using .yml instead of using .yaml like the file is actually called.

Comment: This answer is incomplete, it is not only the file extension that matters

Answer (score 5):

'When using the `azure_rm` inventory plugin, the **NAME** of the inventory file actually matters for parsing.

It has to end with either of the following:

- `azure_rm.yml`
- `azure_rm.yaml`

E.g any of the following filenames are valid:

- `inventory_azure_rm.yml`
- `inventoryazure_rm.yml`
- `why_is_this_a_good_idea_azure_rm.yml`

If the file does not end with ***`azure_rm.yml`*** you will get a generic error message like so:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse $FILENAME with auto plugin: inventory config '$FILENAME ' could not be verified by plugin 'azure_rm'
```